# Equivalent of exec 3<>/dev/tcp/anyaddress.com/80 in ash

Tags: linux, bash, sockets, ash

In bash the following command open a socket

```
exec 3<>/dev/tcp/192.168.1.200/8080
```

In the ash this command does not work. Are there an equivalent of this command for ash?

here after the output error of the command in ash:

```
-ash: can't create /dev/tcp/192.168.1.200/8080: nonexistent directory
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there is not. The standard POSIX bourne shell doesn't offer this feature.

You may be able to accomplish what you need with [socat](http://www.dest-unreach.org/socat/) or [nc](http://linux.die.net/man/1/nc).

This bash feature is very strange by the way, considering that it pretends that there is a directory called `/dev/tcp` which does not actually exist.

Comment: `gawk` is strange in very similar way.